# Understanding syntax of conditional statements in shell script

Tags: shell, makefile

I do see certain statements in a  pre-written Makefile target, where they are invoking the shell to execute certain commands. Following is the syntax of the one which I am puzzled about.

```
[ -z "$(ENV_VAR)" ] || \
echo Building $(ENV_VAR); \
```

So my questions in the above statement are:

(1) Is this a conditional statement that checks the existence of an environment variable?

(2) What does the -z option mean.

(3) As of I know **"||"** is a logical operator, how does it behave in such a use case.

Comment: Are you sure it is not ${ENV_VAR} instead of $(ENV_VAR) ?

Comment: Yes Iam sure that it is $(ENV_VAR). Also please be noted that these commands are within a makefile target, where they are invoking a shell to execute this.

Comment: `[ -z ... ] || echo ...` is a double negation.  Our poor human brain fares better with the equivalent `[ -n ... ] && echo ...`   Also, a warning: The final `; \` in the `Makefile` snippet suggests that more code follows this part.  Note that the condition `[ ... ] || `  only affects the `echo ...` command.  Everything after the last semicolon will be executed unconditionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. `-z`: Expression is true, if the length of following string has zero length
3. `cmd1 || cmd2`: Execution of `cmd2` if `cmd1` returns with a status not equal to zero (i.e., `cmd1` fails)

Comment: Thanks much!!.Just one more clarification, what if "||" is replaced by an "&&"

Comment: Then, `cmd2` will be *only* executed, if `cmd1` was successful (i.e., returns status zero).

Comment: Okay that helps understanding!!